# Ofuscar CSS e JavaScript gratuitamente

Tags: javascript, css, ofuscação

Boa tarde pessoal, estou desenvolvendo uma pagina e gostaria de ofuscar o CSS e Javascript(AngularJS), fiz uma rápida pesquisa na internet e vi algumas ferramenta pagas, e algumas ferramentas Free faziam o ofuscamento de forma muito básica sendo possível manualmente voltar as propriedades originais para leitura e também muito limitada como deixando ofuscar 10 arquivos por vez etc.

Existe alguma forma simples, gratuita e eficaz?

Comment: Cara meu código é naturalmente ofuscado, isso é um risco, nem mesmo eu entendo...lol

Comment: Não vejo necessidade para ofuscamento de código, mas se você tiver um conhecimento básico com node, existem alguns "compiladores" que facilitam bastante :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para JS as duas ferramentas que eu usei diretamente são: [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) e [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

Ambas vão além de uma simples substituição nos nomes das variáveis. Elas analisam o código e podem produzir uma versão do seu código ainda menor ao detectar funções ou blocos mortos (inatingíveis.)

Hoje em dia, na maioria dos casos pra mim, eu não mais uso essas ferramentas diretamente. Elas terminam sendo invocadas como parte de um pipeline. Tipo, eu escrevo meu código em ES6, daí algo assim: `*.js (ES6)` ➔ `Webpack` ➔ `Babel` ➔ `*.js (ES5)` ➔ `Uglify` ➔ `combinação (bundling)` ➔ `browser`.

Já para CSS, fica difícil ofuscar porque os nomes das classes precisam ser os mesmos utilizados no seu HTML e JS. Mesmo assim dá para comprimir um bocado. No passado utilizei o [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) mas hoje também já deixo isso tudo por conta de um pipeline. Eu escrevo meus stylesheets em [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) e segue-se: `*.less` ➔ `Webpack` ➔ `lessc` ➔ `*.css` ➔ `minificação` ➔ `combinação (bundling)` ➔ `browser`.

Alguns dos ítens acima são mais difíceis de utilizar com Angular 1, especialmente Webpack. Mas você pode excluí-los ou buscar alternativas.

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio, utilizei o UglifyJS**2** e realizou o processo conforme minha expectativa, alem da biblioteca unificar todos arquivos JS e realizar toda minificação e ofuscação, já o css vou fazer apenas a minificação.

Comment: Criei um modelo com um .BAT no windows e talvez seja util para a comunidade, `uglifyjs ENTRADA1.js ENTRADA2.js -o SAIDA-UNICA.min.js -p 5 -c -m`

Comment: @ErickV se você acha que minha resposta resolveu seu problema, agradeceria marcá-la como resposta aceita ;)