# "proteger" código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, segurança

Boa tarde prezados(as), sei que a programação Client-Side é vulnerável e não existe proteção. Porém, existem técnicas (não sei o nome) que comprimem ou embolam o código. Eu já vi algo relacionado, mas tem muito tempo e não estou encontrando.

Alguém sabe se existe alguma maneira de "proteger" o código? Ou pelo menos deixar o mesmo ilegível?

Comment: Você pode encontrar a resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154322/ofuscar-css-e-javascript-gratuitamente). Possível duplicada.

Comment: Ofuscador! Perfeito, desculpa a postagem, por procurar relacionado a "proteger código" só encontrava publicações referentes a php e etc. Agradeço, mas vou remover o tópico.

Comment: Infelizmente as pessoas acreditam nisso. Se precisa proteger de fato o ofuscador não resolve, se não precisa então não tem porque usá-lo. Até porque quem acha que precisa geralmente faz um código que ninguém quer acessar aquilo. E se precisa mesmo a solução é outra.

Comment: Entendo, não é nem questão de proteger, o que quero mesmo é apenas deixar ilegível para evitar que qualquer um leia as funções.

Comment: É possível desofuscar. Não precisa remover a pergunta, duplicadas são boas pois servem como índice para outras, como voce mesmo disse que não encontrou nada com a palavra "proteger", sua pergunta vai encaminhar para as respostas.

Comment: Entendido. Mais uma vez obrigado.